# ImageView custom height based on TextView height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, height

Hi I have a problem setting the height of a ImageView based on the height of a TextView, this is the code I'm using:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.abstractText.setText(events.get(position).abstractTExt);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = holder.abstractText.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds((String) holder.abstractText.getText(),0,holder.abstractText.getText().length(),bounds);

    holder.abstractText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, holder.abstractText.getHeight() + 300);
            holder.borderImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
```

the problem is that everything works great till I begin to scroll the RecyclerView, when I scroll the height of the image is smaller than the TextView, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main structure must be like this: (height of RelativeLayout = wrap_content ,height of TextView = wrap_content, height of ImageView = match_parent)

```
<RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/any"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and If you are using RecycyclerView Please tray this:

```
 @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return position;
 }
```

Comment: The structure of the xml is correct but the problem is always presents, do you have an example of "recycle inflated view with (View.getTag())" because I don't know what it is, thanks!